# Code for non-linear constraints in CPlex opl

Tags: variables, constraints, cplex, exponential, nonlinear-equation

`Can anyone help me to code this constraint in Cplex opl . It seems to be nonlinear constraint but I do not know how to convert to linear constraint correctly:"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PfCo.png)
l_jt_y[J][T] and p_jkt_y[J][K][T] are derived variables

Comment: Your decision variables are continuous or discrete ?

Comment: @AlexFleischer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77644193/non-linear-constraints-in-cplex-opl This is the full code and all constraints of the problem. Can you help me with that?